# How to restart workflow if a document is reuploaded?

Tags: workflow, document, file-upload, restart

I have a workflow set up which works really well. Now I want to set a condition on the workflow so that it restarts from Step 1 if a document is re-uploaded (not edited in Office Online). Is there an EASY(I am new to SP) way of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Look into event receivers.

There is no event receiver for re-uploading (overwritting) an attachment. But maybe you can 'detect' a 're-upload' yourself.

A workarround might be (did not try this myself):

- detect an 'ItemAttachmentDeleted' event.
- store a flag on the list item
- when you detect an 'ItemAttachmentAdded' within x seconds it is an 're-upload'
- Start the needed workflow by using code.

Overview of all possible events
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff408183(v=office.14).aspx

Create an event receiver
http://onceinawhilescribble.blogspot.be/2013/05/creating-simple-event-receiver-in.html

Start a workflow by code
http://blog.mmasood.com/2012/06/programatically-start-workflow.html